# ReactJS third party apis stops working on local after build

Tags: reactjs, npm, react-router, http-proxy

My ReactJS app has nothing but client-side and Third Part API integration. My app works totally fine along with third-party APIs if run on my local by

> npm start

Making build through

> npm run build

Then I'm serving up the build on my local by

> serve -l 3000 -s build

Even tried running it on different port, example `serve -s build -l 4000`

and Build's app runs successfully on my local but APIs stops working, I start getting an error

> **You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.**

This is my *Package.json* file

```
{
  "name": "****",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.3",
    "@mui/material": "^5.0.6",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "antd": "^4.16.13",
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "bootstrap": "5.1.3",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "^2.0.4",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "material-ui-color": "^1.2.0",
    "material-ui-popup-state": "^2.0.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "rc-color-picker": "^1.2.6",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.0.0",
    "react-bootstrap-range-slider": "^3.0.3",
    "react-bootstrap-timezone-picker": "^2.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-icons": "^4.3.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.6",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "react-switch": "^6.0.0",
    "react-time-picker": "^4.4.4",
    "react-toastify": "^8.1.0",
    "rgb-hex": "^4.0.0",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "PORT": "3000"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

This is the fetch request for login which doesn't work in case of build on local or on live

```
      await fetch('api/v4/auth/login', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          Accept: 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          authenticationDetails: {
            applicationId: '****',
            email: email,
            password: password,
          },
          deviceDetails: {
            applicationVersion: '154',
            deviceId: '12345678',
            deviceModel: 'PIXEL',
            deviceType: 'PHONE',
            osType: 'ANDROID',
            osVersion: '9',
            timezone: {
              currentTimeInClientInMilliseconds: 0,
              offsetFromUTCInMilliseconds: 0,
              timeZoneId: 'UTC',
            },
          },
        }),
      })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((result) => {
          if (result.errorCode === 401) {
            toast.error('Incorrect email or pasword!', {
              position: 'top-right',
              autoClose: 3000,
              hideProgressBar: true,
              closeOnClick: true,
              pauseOnHover: false,
              draggable: true,
              progress: undefined,
            });
          } else if (result.accessToken) {
            localStorage.setItem('token', result.accessToken);
            history.push('/dashboard');
            toast.success('User logged in successfully', {
              position: 'top-right',
              autoClose: 3000,
              hideProgressBar: true,
              closeOnClick: true,
              pauseOnHover: false,
              draggable: true,
              progress: undefined,
            });
          } else {
            toast.error('Error! While connecting to server', {
              position: 'top-right',
              autoClose: 3000,
              hideProgressBar: true,
              closeOnClick: true,
              pauseOnHover: false,
              draggable: true,
              progress: undefined,
            });
          }
        })
        .catch((error) =>
          toast.error('Error! While connecting to server', {
            position: 'top-right',
            autoClose: 3000,
            hideProgressBar: true,
            closeOnClick: true,
            pauseOnHover: false,
            draggable: true,
            progress: undefined,
          })
        );
```

There's a proxy setup as well

```
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = function (app) {
  app.use(
    createProxyMiddleware('/api', {
      target: 'example.com', // API endpoint 1
      changeOrigin: true,
      pathRewrite: {
        '^/api': '',
      },
      headers: {
        Connection: 'keep-alive',
      },
    })
  );
  app.use(
    createProxyMiddleware('/control', {
      target: 'example2.com', // API endpoint 2
      changeOrigin: true,
      pathRewrite: {
        '^/control': '',
      },
      headers: {
        Connection: 'keep-alive',
      },
    })
  );
};
```

To produce the error, enter some gibberish username and password. You'll see the result as following in the network tab:

[image]

[image]

Some people suggested I should have the same port when I run and I have made sure that both my app and build runs on port 3000.

I need to be able to run the build on localhost, if anyone wishes to see the project on live you may check https://dev.timeahead.co or https://624055f087ea1422bb7d7a5d--stellular-lolly-7512e5.netlify.app/ it throws the same error.

Comment: Are you serving up your local build or just opening the built `index.html` file? https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/ Is your server also running locally on the same network? Do you need to [proxy](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/) your APIs?

Comment: @DrewReese i am serving the local build on port 3000

Comment: @DrewReese I updated my question, elaborated a bit more about the serving part

Comment: Maybe you have disabled JavaScript from your Browser or pinned some security stuff that block it.

Comment: @Leonardo nope, I havent disabled JS there's definately something blocking but i believe resides in the app settings itself

Comment: The URL you linked in your question appears to be running; I see no errors. Have you tried another browser? Tried an incognito window? Etc...?

Comment: @DrewReese i'll add the error screenshot to my question as well, there's only issue with API hitting on live

Comment: Hi @HabibRehman you can check out my answer below

Comment: Hi @kvooak, thanks for taking the time to reply but unfortunately that doesn't solve the problem I have tried it already as I'm using React JS only, its just front end no backend is attached to it so the given path becomes irrelevant as i have proxy setup for APIs only

Comment: Both the links you shared [https://dev.timeahead.co/](https://dev.timeahead.co/) and [https://624055f087ea1422bb7d7a5d--stellular-lolly-7512e5.netlify.app/](https://624055f087ea1422bb7d7a5d--stellular-lolly-7512e5.netlify.app/) both load without issue for me. I don't see any errors. It seems you've disabled Javascript locally in your browser. Did you ever try a different browser or incognito mode?

Comment: @DrewReese I'm sorry where in my question it feels like I'm complaining about page not being loaded? Issue is with APIs i posted clear picture of network tabs

Comment: Ok, I see now, I entered jibberish into the login field and tried logging in. I get a 200OK response back from the backend. It looks like it's trying to send back your React app as a response. You ***are*** running your backend server on a ***different*** port than your frontend app, right?

Comment: @DrewReese i served port 3000 after i made build, and when i run react without build on my local it serves on 3000 as well so i believe ports are the same as well

Comment: @DrewReese this time i did `serve -s build -l 4000` still same issue on 4000

Comment: I think you've gone on a tangent here with the frontend. Are you sure your server is running and configured correctly? If you use Postman to make these API requests do you get expected valid responses?

Comment: @DrewReese Nothing wrong with APIs other than it doesn't allow CORS, It works fine on PostMan, works fine if we hit through server, works fine if we simply run it on local without build only issue arise when we make the build and run that build the APIs stops working

Comment: Your server isn't even running.

Comment: @SarhadSalam what do you mean by that

Comment: @HabibRehman is it working now ?

Comment: @Subhanshu NO xD we are working on putting the API calls in the Backend and not through React Frontend

Comment: I'll delete this question once past two days

Comment: Where are you seeing "You need to enable JavaScript to run this app."? The screenshot you posted shows this in the *preview* of a request, which is not an issue. Do you also see that message in the console? That is where it would cause an issue. https://github.com/http-party/node-http-proxy might be helpful for you if the sole use of your backend is to proxy API calls to 3rd parties.

Answer (score 0):

In server side you are trying render react app, when you make post request to server its just returning react app's index file

Proxy Middleware works automatically in [Development server only](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/#:%7E:text=Note%3A%20You%20do%20not%20need%20to%20import%20this%20file%20anywhere.%20It%20is%20automatically%20registered%20when%20you%20start%20the%20development%20server.)
If you want to proxy in production then you need to create separate express application

Serving with [Serve package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve) itself is not sufficient as serve is used to serve a static site and no server side logic(here proxy) will be evaluated

Sample will be

```
    const express = require('express');
    const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');
    
    const app = express();
    
    app.use(
    createProxyMiddleware('/api', {
      target: 'example.com', // API endpoint 1
      changeOrigin: true,
      pathRewrite: {
        '^/api': '',
      },
      headers: {
        Connection: 'keep-alive',
      },
    })
  );
  app.use(
    createProxyMiddleware('/control', {
      target: 'example2.com', // API endpoint 2
      changeOrigin: true,
      pathRewrite: {
        '^/control': '',
      },
      headers: {
        Connection: 'keep-alive',
      },
    })
  );
    app.listen(80);
```

now just run `node filename.js` along with `serve -s build -l 4000`

Since Server is running on different port you need to make necessary changes while serving through serve

If you want serve react through Express then add below code to above

```
// add middleware
app.use(express.static("public"));
```

If we are serving on same port no changes are required in react app

Comment: With this solution, should there be some configuration change on the app so it sends request to the proxy server? Also, since the app server and proxy server are not the same origin, should the proxy server support XORS request?

Comment: @tigerpaw updated answer , If you serve react with express then no changes required else we need to point the request URL correctly to port on which it is running,

Comment: if server is in different domain and react app is in different domain then we need to configure express to enable CORS , but in general we deploy in same domain

Comment: your solution doesn't work it sill gives CORS error @saivineeth

Comment: post screenshot of your error and code also. Did you configured CORS in Express?? @HabibRehman